# Two divs rolling one to the top and another to bottom of screen (opening animation)

Tags: css, animation

this is my first post to the stack overflow community, I am a beginner, and after a week of googling, I decided to ask for help here. I wanted to make an animation, where the screen is divided into two boxes, both have the same width as the screen and height 50% of screen height (one box on another box). And those two boxes should roll, one down to the bottom of the screen and the top one to the top of the screen (then there will be a Gmail icon that will open just as the divs do. I tried to make an animation in adobe after effects and use it as a video but it wasn´t responsive on other devices. So I made SVGs of an icon and use divs that roll up but it has two major problems.

1. **2. When divs rolls up and down, you can scroll the screen and I don´t want that, I want it to be static.**
2. **When I looked at the mobile perspective it turned out to be horrible to first div was ok but the second rolled to the middle and stopped there**

Here´s my code that I´ve tried, I´ve tried my best.

```css
body {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #f1f2f1;
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
}


/*divs*/

.divko1 {
  transition: height 2s ease;
  height: 0 !important;
}

.divko2 {
  transition: margin 2s ease;
  margin-top: 50% !important;
}

#div1 {
  background-color: #1A4335;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100vw;
}

#div2 {
  margin: 0%;
  background-color: #BA4335;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100vw;
}


/*icons*/

.icons {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  width: 11em;
  height: 10em;
}


/*content*/

#content {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#content * {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Maily na prenajom</title>
  <link href="./style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body style="margin: 0;">
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <img style="margin-top:1.6em;" class="icons" src="/test/vrch.svg" alt="top of gmail icon">
  <img style="margin-top:3.7em;" class="icons" src="/test/spodok.svg" alt="bottom of gmail icon">
  <div id="div2"></div>
  <div id="content">
    <!-- content belongs here -->
  </div>
  <script>
    const div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
    const div2 = document.getElementById("div2");

    function css() {
      div1.classList.add("divko1");
      div2.classList.add("divko2");
      setTimeout(remove, 1800);
    }

    function remove() {
      div1.remove();
      div2.remove();
      button.remove();
      document.getElementById("content").style.visibility = "visible";
      css()
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I just don´t know what to do anymore so if anyone sees a solution here or a simple tip for me I would really be thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `transition` need to be on the class that doesn't do the "change".

Nothing is executing your css() function. You can use a EventListener to execute your code on the load of your document like this :

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
 //code
});
```

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
    const div2 = document.getElementById("div2");

    div1.classList.add("divko1");
    div2.classList.add("divko2");
    
    // disable overflow during animation
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    setTimeout(remove, 1800);

    function remove() {
      div1.remove();
      div2.remove();
      document.body.style.overflow = "scroll";
      document.getElementById("content").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #f1f2f1;
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  }


/*divs*/

.divko1 {
  height: 0 !important;
}

.divko2 {
  margin-top: 50% !important;
}

#div1 {
  background-color: #1A4335;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100vw;  
  transition: height 2s ease;
}

#div2 {
  margin: 0%;
  background-color: #BA4335;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100vw;
  transition: margin 2s ease;
}

/*icons*/

.icons {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  width: 11em;
  height: 10em;
}


/*content*/

#content {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#content * {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Maily na prenajom</title>
  <link href="./style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body style="margin: 0;">
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <img style="margin-top:1.6em;" class="icons" src="/test/vrch.svg" alt="top of gmail icon">
  <img style="margin-top:3.7em;" class="icons" src="/test/spodok.svg" alt="bottom of gmail icon">
  <div id="div2"></div>
  <div id="content">
    <!-- content belongs here -->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It wasn´t 100% what I was looking for (because I had more problems that I didn´t mention here) But you definitely showed me the way how to solve everything! Thanks a lot!